# How to cast UnsafeMutableRawPointer! to UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> in Swift 3.0 or newer?

Tags: ios, swift, accelerate-framework, unsafemutablepointer, vimage

I am working with Accelerate library for my iOS app. I built this app in Swift 2.0 a couple years ago and it was working fine. Now that Swift is updated to 3.0 and 4.0, I have to convert most of the code to the current syntax. I have run the converter but I still have some syntax errors. This is the one that I am having trouble the most fixing. I couldn't seem to find an equivalently succinct way to fix it.

I made functions for basic arithmetic operation on images. 
This is one of them:

```
public func add(_ left: Image, right: Image) -> Image! {
    let results = Image.init(rows: left.size.rows, columns: left.size.columns, pixelSize: left.pixelSize)
    let leftOperand = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(left.buffer.data)
    let rightOperand = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(right.buffer.data)
    let destination = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(results.buffer.data)
    vDSP_vadd(leftOperand, 1, rightOperand, 1, destination, 1, UInt(left.lengthOfBuffer))
    return results
}
```

The class `Image` has a field `buffer` which is a `vImage_Buffer`and is defined like such,

```
open class Image {

open var buffer: vImage_Buffer

....}
```

***The problem:***
Calling `buffer.data` returns a type of `UnsafeMutableRawPointer!`. The `vDSP_add` function requires `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>` for its parameters. I used to be able to cast it to an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>` object right away. Looks like the initializer is deprecated now. Thus, on the codes like `let leftOperand = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(left.buffer.data)`, I get this error

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer!)'.
```

I don't know if I overlook something very simple here, yet I still haven't fixed this. But, I am looking for a solution that doesn't require manually copying each element using a loop, since this function is called pretty frequently in the app.

Just some documentation links that might help:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage_buffer
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450275-vdsp_vsadd
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer#topics

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`assumingMemoryBound(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawpointer/2431721-assumingmemorybound):

> Returns a typed pointer to the memory referenced by this pointer, assuming that the memory is already bound to the specified type.

In your case:

```
let leftOp = left.buffer.data.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)
let rightOp = right.buffer.data.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)
// ...
```

See [UnsafeRawPointer Migration](https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift3/se-0107-migrate.html) for more information.

Comment: I think this might solve the problem. At least, I don't get a compiler error. I will give an update as soon as I've got the other errors fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @KeenR.D.: Any progress? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: thank you for following up. I got all of the conversion done. But, I am still trying to figure out this code signing problem. Once it got resolved, I’ll keep you updated.

Comment: I have got the app running again. Your solution works! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem.

```
public func add(_ left: Image, right: Image) -> Image! {
let results = Image.init(rows: left.size.rows, columns: left.size.columns, pixelSize: left.pixelSize)
var leftOperand = Float(left.buffer.data)
var rightOperand = Float(right.buffer.data)
var destination = Float(results.buffer.data)
vDSP_vadd(&leftOperand, 1, &rightOperand, 1, &destination, 1, UInt(left.lengthOfBuffer))
return results
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! The `data` itself is a pointer since it is part of the `vImage_buffer`. I got an error trying to cast it into a `Float`. Seems like `assumingMemoryBound(to:):` might work for me.